# Count words and read buffer of recorded .wav file

Tags: c#, wav

I have a task to add to my c# program a recording control which will view a visualizer graph during recording and save the recording as a .wav file.
After the recording ended i would need to analysis and investigate into the .wav file and check how many words are in the recording and check a few more things in the shape of the graph such as the way the user pronounced the syllables etc.
Any idea which libraries are the best to use or how to start programming this?

(I would prefer to write code implementing an existing interface/dll etc.)

Comment: NAudio [link](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) is good for your tasks.